# having trouble with isSuffix function in Haskell

Tags: haskell

i want to check if a list is a suffix of the other. 
I'm struggling with this, for a while know.

Here's my code:

```
isSuffix :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
isSuffix [] _ = False
isSuffix _ [] = False
isSuffix xs ys = sufix (take (length ys) (reverse xs)) (reverse ys)
    where sufix [] [] = False
          sufix (x:xs) (y:ys) 
              | (x == y)  = sufix xs ys
```

This doesn't work, and i can't find the error.

UPDATE:

```
isSuffix :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
isSuffix [] _ = False
isSuffix _ [] = False
isSuffix xs ys = sufix (take (length ys) (reverse xs)) (reverse ys)
   where sufix [] [] = False
      sufix [] _ = False
      sufix _ [] = False
      sufix (x:xs) (y:ys) = x == y && sufix xs ys
```

Comment: Hint: which clause can return `True`?

Comment: @DanielWagner the whole ideia is, if it checks out til the end, ir returns true.

Comment: I understand the _idea_, of course. I'm asking, _which of the clauses that you wrote_ can return `True`?

Comment: The clause where i make the comparison, it returns true if it checks, false if it does not @DanielWagner

Comment: Okay. That may be a misunderstanding of how guards work, then, and will guide my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There's a few problems here. The first is that there seems to be a misunderstanding of how guards work. From your comments, it sounds like you believe that

```
f | p1 = p2
```

will return `p1` in some cases, but this is not true: `p1` is only used to decide whether to return `p2` or continue on to a next clause. One possible fix for this is to change your guard line like this:

```
sufix (x:xs) (y:ys) = x == y && sufix xs ys
```

A second problem is that your patterns for `sufix` are not complete: they do not handle the case where one list is longer than the other. You can turn on `-fwarn-incomplete-patterns` and see what I mean:

```
test.hs:5:11: Warning:
    Pattern match(es) are non-exhaustive
    In an equation for ‘sufix’:
        Patterns not matched:
            [] (_ : _)
            (_ : _) []
```

When you work out what answers to put for these patterns, I think you will see what I was aiming at with my hint about when you return `True`!

Comment: Please check my update. It compiles now, but still does not work properly

Comment: @laker001 When the details of a question changes, the usual etiquette here is to open a separate question. But my answer is the same hint: which clause can return `True`? (My answer: none of them! Why?)

Comment: in this case, the `sufix (x:xs) (y:ys) = x == y && sufix xs ys` expression should return `True`or `False`, since it is a `AND` operation, am i right ?

Comment: @laker001 For it to return `True`, you must find both that `x == y` and that `sufix xs ys` -- and the latter can't return `True` in the first place. So you'll have to look harder to find a place that returns `True`!